# API JSON cannot be parsed correctly

Tags: json, codeigniter

I am writing a web API with codeigniter, here is one of my result:

http://manage.pineconetassel.com/index.php/api/v1/colors2

It looks close to right, but if I feed it into hurl.it (GET testing service, sorry cannot post url here)

it cannot be parsed, correctly. it shows "colors", but no values

To compare, the following JSON can be parsed correctly by hurl.it
http://www.w3schools.com//website/Customers_JSON.php

what is wrong with my code? The code generating this API is the following:

model:

```
public function get_colors2(){
    $q = $this->publicDB->select('color')->get('car_colors');
    if ($q->num_rows > 0) {
        return $q->result_array();
    } else {return FALSE;}
}
```

I am using Phil Sturgeon's RESTful server implementation

controller:

```
    function colors2_get()
    {
        $result = $this->api_model->get_colors2();
        if ($result) {
            $this->response($result,200);
        } else {$this->response(NULL,404);}
    }
```

Comment: I am not having issues with running your URL through Hurl.it It shows a perfect response. What is your issue? http://picpaste.com/Untitled3-3TquAmaO.png

Comment: here is a screen shot http://picpaste.com/parse_error-R8cossDN.png

Comment: That confounds me as I have run it multiple times in Hurl.it and its working fine for me. The only thing I can think of is that for some reason the call does not work from your specific IP. Try testing this from a phone or anything from a different IP.

Comment: I tried on 3 different computers (similar IP), all failed in parsing the JSON
On the other hand, I tried curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET http://manage.pineconetassel.com/index.php/api/v1/colors2
And it works. I am suprised by this result.

Comment: Are all the computers behind the same router? (At a school lab or at your house)? If so then they have the same external ip. Idk what else to say it's still working for me.

Comment: I tried it using Runscope to make the request and it works fine too https://www.runscope.com/public/196bfc03-e52c-4bb2-932b-b466da7b363d/ab0c500a-2308-4e28-8a4e-8e86713dcaba